# VS2013 Cordova blank app command failed with exit code 8 error

Tags: android, node.js, cordova, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-cordova

I've create a new Blank App (Apache Cordova) typescript in VS2013 community edition.
Running the ripple emulator works fine. But when I attempt to run the android emulator or device, then I get this error:

> C:\WorkspaceMobileVisualStudio\BlankCordovaApp1\BlankCordovaApp1\bld\Debug\platforms\android\cordova\build.bat: Command failed with exit code 8    C:\WorkspaceMobileVisualStudio\BlankCordovaApp1\BlankCordovaApp1\MDAVSCLI

The output is:

> 1>------ Build started: Project: BlankCordovaApp1, Configuration: Debug Android 1>  GeneratedJavascript=scripts\index.js;scripts\platformOverrides.js
>   1>  C:\WorkspaceMobileVisualStudio\BlankCordovaApp1\BlankCordovaApp1>call "C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\"\nodevars.bat 
>   1>  Your environment has been set up for using Node.js 0.10.33 (ia32) and npm.
>   1>  ------ Ensuring correct global installation of package from source package directory: C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 12.0\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\1LHTZMLE.C0Y\packages\vs-mda
>   1>MDAVSCLI : error : C:\WorkspaceMobileVisualStudio\BlankCordovaApp1\BlankCordovaApp1\bld\Debug\platforms\android\cordova\build.bat: Command failed with exit code 8
>   ========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
>   ========== Deploy: 0 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========

I have seen questions where the answer has been to check path variables JAVA_HOME, ADT_HOME, and ANT_HOME, which I have done, and they are all correct. The other common issue appears to be spaces in the workspace, which I did have, but I've now created a new workspace folder.

As far as I'm aware I should be able to see the "Hello, your application is ready!" screen.

Comment: I'm still having issues with my setup here. Though I'm now getting exit code 1 instead of 8.
If I run the build.bat directly in the command line then it works fine, but I want to be able to debug through visual studio.
I'll take any suggestions!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Turned out to be an issue with the Node.js version I was using: 0.12. I uninstalled this and ran the .msi installer for version 0.10.28 from here: http://nodejs.org/dist/v0.10.28/

Worth noting that this still does not like numbers or spaces in the workspace directory!

Comment: This worked for me too! I'm on VS 2013 Update 4. Thanks.